# Dagster chaining resources

Tags: dagster

I've recently picked up Dagster to evaluate as an alternate to Airflow.

I haven't been able to wrap my head around the concept of **resources** and looking to understand if what I'm trying to do is possible or can be achieved better in a different way.

I have a helpder class like below that helps keep code DRY

```
from dagster import resource, solid, ModeDefinition, pipeline
from dagster_aws.s3 import s3_resource

class HelperAwsS3:
    def __init__(self, s3_resource):
        self.s3_resource = s3_resource

    def s3_list_bucket(self, bucket, prefix):
        return self.s3_resource.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Prefix=prefix
        )

    def s3_download_file(self, bucket, file, local_path):
        self.s3_resource.meta.client.download_file(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=file,
            Filename=local_path
        )

    def s3_upload_file(self, bucket, file, local_path):
        self.s3_resource.meta.client.upload_file(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=file,
            Filename=local_path
        )
```

The *s3_resource* is actually *dagster_aws.s3.s3_resource* which will help me connect to AWS using my local aws credenitals.

I am not sure how to pass the *s3_resource* to the HelperAwsS3 when I make the call in the **@resource** section below.

```
@resource
def connection_helper_aws_s3_resource(context):
    return HelperAwsS3()
```

Any pointers please? Or am I doing it all wrong and it needs doing in a different way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question on the dagster Slack channel and qickly had a reply frok the helpful team. Posting it here, in case it helps someone -

*keep your HelperAwsS3 class and write your own resource that uses the s3 resource, it could look something like this:*

```
@resource(required_resource_keys={"s3"})
def connection_helper_aws_s3_resource(context):
    return HelperAwsS3(s3_resource=context.resources.s3)
```

*(And then be sure to include both the s3 resource and your custom resource on your mode definition:*

```
@pipeline(mode_defs=[ModeDefinition(
  resource_defs={"s3": s3_resource, "connection_helper_aws_s3": connection_helper_aws_s3_resource}
)]):
  ...
```